# Laravel 7: How to prevent middleware Authenticate from redirecting when user is not authenticated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have implemented the middleware Authenticate with `$this->middleware('auth:api');`.

The application is a REST API so I don't need Laravel to redirect the client. I need it to return a JSON response.

There is a method `redirectTo` inside `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php;`. This method only accepts a route, therefore I cannot add the JSON response to this method.

How can I use the middleware Authenticate `(auth:api)` and return a JSON Response when the user is not authenticated?

Answer (score 7):

Laravel already does this when the request expects a JSON response. So, as long as you're either sending AJAX requests or you're sending requests with the `Accept` header set properly (`application/json` or `*`), Laravel will automatically respond with a 401 JSON response.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

This class is extending `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` - and it overrides `redirectTo` method. You need to write down your own handle method. If you want you may remove `extends` part if you don't need framework's authenticate method.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'you shall not pass']);
    }

    // other checks

    return $next($request);
}
```

Another option would be keeping the `extends` and calling parent method after doing your regular checks if you need some of the functionality from base class.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'you shall not pass']);
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next, $guards);
}
```