# Laravel - How to cancel redirecting to login when unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel

In my project, I using laravel as `api`

> UserController > profile() `need token to run`

For example when I call it without **token**, laravel display error which **"Route [login] not defined"** *and it's right because we don't have any template in laravel.*

How can I return **json response** instead redirect to login page as html?

```
public function profile(): JsonResponse
{
    //using protected method
    return response()->json($this->guard()->user());
}
```

Comment: when you access an api route via browser you'll be redirect but when you access the route by passing proper header ``accept: application/json`` you'll get the response instead of redirection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel API routes not working with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424901/laravel-api-routes-not-working-with-postman)

Comment: @OMiShah actually I using postman to test it

Comment: In api you need to send json data instead of attempting login and redirecting.

Comment: @LeenaPatel I get this error from Authenticate middleware, can u explain what do u mean ?

Comment: Check this answer if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073356/3348994

Comment: Thanks to you @LeenaPatel, I get the answer by your reference

Answer (score 1):

Open Authenticate file `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

add reference

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

put this code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (!Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Error Message!']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: But after that I can't do anymore auth()->user or Auth::user because the user it's always null

Answer (score 0):

You can make middleware manually and in the middleware you can check user if exists. For example, if you use JWT token, then you can write like that as app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php :

```php
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

        /* Check is token filled */
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'status' => 401,
                'message' => 'Bad authorization',
                'data' => []
            ], 401);

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

For route partion:

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth'
], function () {
  Route::get('/profile', 'User@profile');
});
```

Comment: Hmm, no, not worked

Comment: I changed mycodes. Pls, try again

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you can do is you can create a customized Auth middleware which returns a JSON response.
Or you can use a simple condition in your function:

```
  if (Auth::check()){
      //if logged in user exists
  } else {
      //if logged in user does not exist
  }
```

Comment: It's not the solution, that because `laravel` check the token using middleware and it's before the controller, and my question is return `json` instead redirecting to login page.

Comment: yes so can you show me the route file code?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you want to edit is located in **app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php** in the function **redirectTo**

Comment: no it's not, and please put your answer as comment in the question